# Creating a new user and also add new data to the firebase database at every SignUp

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android programming. I am working on an app. When I signup in my app this shows the previously added data and does not ask me to add new user data to the database.
Even if I again login with a registered user then it again shows the previously added data.
I want that when I create a new user then a new node should create and then its child with data.

Database Picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need unique id to share your data in firebase. You can use user id for that. If you use firebase authentication. you can get user id from

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

You can use this with email password firebase authentication. Likewise, you can get a unique id for authentication. Then u need to use that id as a key of your firebase database. Then your data structure should be changed like below. (key would be userids)

```
childsQuerity
  |-------------adminInfo
                   |-------key1 -> value1
                   |-------asas1234 -> value2

  |-------------childInfo
                   |-------key1 -> value1
                   |-------key2 -> value2
```

in your android activity use below command to push data to db

```
   FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();        
   DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("childInfo").child(userid);

   ref.setValue(userDataUWant);
```

When creating a new user, get userid and update that firebase data like above-mentioned method. Then if an already registered user logged to the system. u can get user id using above mentioned method and you can get that user details as well.

Comment: even if i authenticate with google or facebook accounts ?

Comment: Yeah u need to get id of user  otherwise firebase cannot handle. If you didn't provide key and only provide values, firebase create unique keys and add data to it. But you cannot rettrive data properly without knowing id. I think it is better to use that userid to store data